# Xpages more fields (unlimited) at the click of a button

Tags: xpages

I would like to start with x no. of fields (in my app I have a pair of textual data field and numeric data field) on a xpage application (say 10 pairs) and then when the user clicks on "more field", I want more pairs to appear dynamically without a full refresh on the page, but would like unlimited no. of fields (as long as the page doesn't crash) and then I would like to submit the form and the data for all those fields. What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually, fields are bound to a document data source using dot notation:

```
<inputText value="#{contact.firstName}" />
```

However, array notation is also supported:

```
<inputText value="#{contact['firstName']}" />
```

Because the field name in this latter syntax is being treated as a string, not as an implicit property of the bean, it can be dynamically computed. What I've found to be the easiest way to define these dynamic fields is to create a custom control for each of the basic types of fields, and define each as accepting the data source and the field name. So the field itself then ends up with a syntax similar to the following:

```
<inputText value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.fieldName]}" />
```

By using that syntax, a calculation of any complexity can be used to determine what field name to pass to the custom control. In the scenario you're attempting to accomplish, specifying an indexVar on the repeat control that surrounds the field pair would allow you to designate a field suffix for each... perhaps something like the following:

```
<xp:repeat indexVar="fieldSuffix" value="#{viewScope.rowCount}">
 <xp:div>
  <xc:dynamicInputText dataSource="#{contact}" fieldName="fullName_#{fieldSuffix}" />
  <xc:dynamicInputNumber dataSource="#{contact}" fieldName="phoneNumber_#{fieldSuffix}" />
 </xp:div>
</xp:repeat>
```

With this approach, you would end up with fields named "fullName_0", "fullName_1", etc., up to the limit specified in the viewScope. Typically, the only complication is ensuring that when an existing document is opened, the viewScope variable is set back to the correct limit. Another approach to that, of course, is actually saving the limit as another item on the document and binding the repeat value to it instead.

Comment: Thanks Tim, will definitely give this a go and keep you posted. I haven't tried this, but just wondering if I do a partial refresh of the repeat control, I won't lose existing data?

Comment: I was pretty much going to answer this along the exact same lines, this method will work, I do recommend computing the 'repeat limit' to be the same as the viewScope limit so you don't wonder why new fields aren't appearing after you hit 30.

Comment: Great suggestion, Declan. You can of course also attach a pager to the repeat, but for this type of interface most users would not expect pagination to be available the way they would for view type interfaces, so just forcing the "rows" attribute to always match the limit is probably preferable.

Comment: Thanks Tim and Declan, this is fantastic. It would be a very high value like 1000, but I only want to show 10 after each click on "add more" and show more as an increment on 10, but at the same time don't lose existing data when more is clicked upon. I could either do client side JS trickery or if I did server side partial refresh (which would be ideal) would I lose existing data?

Comment: By default, all partial refresh events post the entire form that is associated with them. So if a user has entered data into any of the fields, then clicks "add more", that new data will be posted during the event invocation. On the other hand, this means that as you approach 1000 rows, this event is likely to get incrementally slower, because it will have to post the value of hundreds of fields regardless of whether their values have changed. It's inherently an inefficient design. But it should still work... it will just be slower than when only a few rows are in use.

Comment: Thanks Tim - so would Stephen's (stwissel) method be any more efficient or is Javabeans the way to go as Toby suggested?

Comment: I'm not certain the approach Stephan recommends would scale to what you're proposing. Due to limits on summary data, if you're using separate fields for each of 1000 rows, then each field can store up to an average of 32 characters before you hit that limit; if you're storing the rows as individual values of 2 fields, then you're limited to an average of 7 characters per field. This article describes those limits in detail... and also proposes an alternative approach to storing complex data: http://xmage.gbs.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-8NKTPN

Comment: Hi Tim, I have implemented this technique, but now require server side validation for each row to check whether product code exists in our database as well as other validation checks. Sine ID cannot be dynamically generated how do I map this onto Error Message control? Happy to post it as a new question, please let me know - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You also can have a look at the exercise 23 "Tablewalker". It doesn't do multiple fields but does Multi-value fields which might be better in terms of processing and storage (you can do an @Elements to find out how many are there in a document). The exercise is here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-23
While the button only adds one row at a time, it is easy to adjust.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is have a Bean with 2 String values Label and Data and a managed bean that has a ArrayList of that object so inside of your repeat control you bind the repeat to the ArrayList and then bind your xp:inputText to rowData.Data and your xp:label to rowData.Label then when you want to add another 5 rows you just add However many more objects into the ArrayList then refresh your page, your data will still live in your arraylist and you will have 5 new Empty objects where you can add data.

```
public class Data {

private String label;
private String data;

public Data() {

}
//getters and setters

}

public class ManagedBean {

private ArrayList<Data> datalist;  // add a managed property for this one so It will create a new one when needed.

// getters and setters

public addFiveMoreObjects() {
   Data newItem;
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
       newItem = new Data();
       datalist.add(newItem);
   }
}

}

<xp:repeat value="#{managedBean.datalist}" var="rowData">
<xp:text value="#{rowData.label}" />
<xp:inputText value="#{rowData.data} />
</xp:repeat>

<xp:button value="Add 5 More"> // call #{managedBean.addFiveMoreObjects}
```

Comment: This looks really interesting and many thanks for sharing. Since I haven't started Javabeans dev yet, I might try the other methods first.